# Too many edges/faces to create smooth surface?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, faces, polycount

I started learning modelling a few days ago, and came across a problem that I haven't yet learned how to solve.
At the moment, I'm modelling a handgun's magazine, and thought about adding multiple vertical loop cuts to make the curves smoother. This was the result (I hope it's visible):
[image: usp_magazine_more_edges] 
But, from what I learned in the past days, having less polygons (and therefore having less edges, I think) is better than having too many of them. So, I removed a few edges to reduce polygon count, and got the following result:
[image: usp_magazine_less_edges]
Now, am I supposed to leave the magazine with more edges, as seen in the first image, or remove the unneeded edges and smooth out the surface later? If so, how can I smooth a surface, or add a curve to it?

Comment: Hi. Please add images directly into the body of question. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post for more information.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the link, I couldn't really figure out how to do it before.

Comment: It is true that more geometry weights more computationally speaking, but how much or how little you need depends largely on the purpose of your model and on the quality/performance ratio you need to achieve. For a game engine or real time display you need to cut down on geometry. For an offline render those few extras will probably not make a significant dent, and are likely needed for better quality. Bottom line is there is no universal number or truth about what to keep or what to remove, use good sense and knowledge of what the purpose of your model is.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the info! I was planning to import my own models into UE4, and this project was only a test at modelling. I will cut down on some of my edges to reduce the polycount. Although with a reduced amount of edges/vertices to work with, how could I add a curve to a polygon? If I digress too much with this question, please tell me, so I can move this question to a different post.

Comment: You can't really curve surfaces without polygons for the most part. You  may bake some nromals maps and use smooth shading to fake smaller details but it will only go so far. If you model needs to be curved that is obviously **not** where you can cut on polygon count. Cut it elsewhere where you can optimize. More importantly [take care of your topology](http://topologyguides.com), if this is to go into a game engine then ngons are a no-go

Comment: Seems like what I want to accomplish is currently above my skill level. Practice makes perfect though, so I guess I will get the hang of this eventually. I did check out the link you sent though, I will see if going through this guide will give me a better understanding on how this works.